# Встроить условие в echo

Tags: php, echo

Всем привет.
Подскажите, как мне в вывод `echo` встроить условие?

```
echo "<div>
    ...
</div>
";
```

А условие такое:

```
<? if(!empty($myrow['year'])): ?>
<span>-</span>
<span>". $myrow['year'] ."</span>
<span>-</span>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: .

    echo '<div>...';
    if (!empty($myrow['year'])) { ?>
        <span>-</span>
        <span><?php echo $myrow['year']; ?></span>
        <span>-</span>
    <?php }
    echo '</div>';

Comment: echo можно выводить не за раз, а фрагментами, так что ответ выше верен, так можно и использовать условия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант первый:

```
<div>
...
<?php
   if(!empty($myrow['year'])){?>
   <span>-</span>
   <span><?=$myrow['year'];?></span>
   <span>-</span>
   <?}
?>
</div>
```

Вариант второй:

```
<? echo "<div>";
if(!empty($myrow['year'])): ?>
<span>-</span>
<span>".$myrow['year']."</span>
<span>-</span>
<? endif;
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Предпочтительнее не использовать echo, так как с ним получается неразбериха в коде. Желательно просто делать вставки php в html-код.

Comment: > Предпочтительнее не использовать echo, так как его применяют в основном начинающие программисты. 

На самом деле потому, что вывод очень быстро превращается в кашу, а к опыту и скорости работы это никакого серьезного практического отношения не имеет (хоть и есть корреляции).

Comment: @IntegralAL, а я читал статью в журнале Лиза, рассказать?

Comment: @Etki ужасный факт. Мы никому об этом не расскажем.

Comment: >Предпочтительнее не использовать echo, так как его применяют в основном начинающие программисты

По сути предложения согласен, но обоснование "потому-что так делают новички" откровенно бредова. Особенно в сочетании с "в одной статье прочитал". Это лечение симптомов, вместо болезни. Карго-культ! "Неопытные программисты используют `echo`, я не буду использовать `echo` и от этого перестану быть неопытным". Без понимания причин это просто бессмысленное правило.

Comment: Ладно короче уберу лишние фразы)

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую функции [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) и `printf()` — они «впечатывают» в темплейт значения. Например, на место "`%s`" встанет значение аргумента как строка. `sprintf()` возвращает результат как строку, `printf()` выводит её, примерно как `echo`.

Что хорошо — отделяется логика от представления.

```
if( empty( $myrow[ 'year'])) {
  $div = "";
} else {
  $div = sprintf(
    "<span>-</span><span>%s</span><span>-</span>",
    $myrow['year']
  );
}
printf( "<div>%s</div>", $div);
```